# Finding particular solution to nonhomogenous linear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Determine the general solution to the system $$X' = \begin{pmatrix} 5 && 3 \\ -1 && 1 \end{pmatrix}X + \begin{pmatrix} -5x + 2 \\-x-3\end{pmatrix}$$

Solving the corresponding homogenous equation gives me $X(x) = c_1 \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} e^{2x} + c_2 \begin{pmatrix} -3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} e^{4x}$. To find a particular solution, I think variation of parameters is suitable. The fundamental matrix $\Psi(x)$ is given by $\Psi(x) = \begin{pmatrix} -e^{2x} && -3e^{4x} \\ e^{2x} && e^{4x} \end{pmatrix}$ and looking for a solution of the form $X_p = \Psi(x)U(x)$ yields $U'(x)= \Psi^{-1}(x) \begin{pmatrix} -5x + 2 \\-x-3\end{pmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} -8xe^{-2x}  -7e^{-2x} \\ 6xe^{-4x} +e^{-4x}\end{pmatrix}$

Since $\int xe^{-ax} dx = -\dfrac{1}{a}xe^{-ax} - \dfrac{1}{a^2}e^{-ax}$ we arrive at $U(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 4xe^{-2x}+2e^{-2x}+7/2e^{-2x} \\ -3/2xe^{-4x}-3/8e^{-4x}-1/4e^{-4x} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 3xe^{-2x} + 7/4e^{-2x} \\-15/16xe^{-4x}-1/8e^{-4x}\end{pmatrix}$

$X_p = \Psi(x) U(x) = \begin{pmatrix} -e^{2x} && -3e^{4x} \\ e^{2x} && e^{4x} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 3xe^{-2x} + 7/4e^{-2x} \\-15/16xe^{-4x}-1/8e^{-4x}\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} -3/16x-11/8 \\ 33/16x+13/8 \end{pmatrix}$

Of course this is all wrong and the professor insists on finding a suitable ansatz. What are the guidelines for coming up with an ansatz to a nonhomogenous linear system?

Comment: Are you saying he wants you to use Undetermined Coefficients as in http://www4.ncsu.edu/eos/users/s/slc/www/COURSES/File2.pdf or are you allowed to any method?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but using UC, I would think a suitable ansatz could be $$x_{1p} = a + bx \\ x_{2p} = c + d x$$.

Comment: @Moo What is meant by "[...] if we multiply by $t^k$ for a root of multiplicity $k+1$ of $p(\lambda)$, we also include the terms multiplied by the lower powers of t"?  (Step 2 on page 408).

Comment: Think about the case where you share an eigenvalue with the particular solution. For example, you get $ce^{-t}$, but the particular solution $...= 5 e^{-t}$. How do you choose a particular solution in that case - you would multiply your choice of a particular solution by $t$? For others, see example 10: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx. By the way, your method (Variation of parameters) works, you just got the wrong result using it.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with using variation of parameters (except that an ansatz might be quicker). It's just that you made a mistake in your computations; the second equality in the line $U(x)=\dots$ is wrong (in both components).